# Convert rosbag file into carmen log file

Tags: slam, rosbag, slam-gmapping

Is it possible to convert a rosbag file to a slam log file in carmen format? I have the bag file available and I need CARMEN style logfiles in a format like the follow:

```
# message_name [message content] ipc_timestamp ipc_hostname logger_timestamp
# message formats defined: PARAM SYNC ODOM FLASER RLASER TRUEPOS
# PARAM param_name param_value
# SYNC tagname
# ODOM x y theta tv rv accel
# FLASER num_readings [range_readings] x y theta odom_x odom_y odom_theta
# RLASER num_readings [range_readings] x y theta odom_x odom_y odom_theta 
# TRUEPOS true_x true_y true_theta odom_x odom_y odom_theta
# NMEA- GGA utc latitude lat_orient longitude long_orient gps_quality num_sattelites hdop sea_level alitude geo_sea_level geo_sep data_age
PARAM robot_use_laser on nohost 0
PARAM simulator_num_readings 180 nohost 0
PARAM robot_frontlaser_offset 0. 0 nohost 0
PARAM robot_rearlaser_offset 0.0 nohost 0
ODOM -0.000602 0.012727 -1.570796 0.000000 0.000000 70.179699 nohost 0.000000
FLASER 180 46.56 47.31 12.51 14. 71 12. 16 12.26 12.21 11.76 10.56 9.46 8.66 7.91 ...
```

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* C24. What have you tried so far? You should be able to open a bagfile and iterate through the messages. If you open a file before opening the bag then you can write to it as you iterate and then you're free to reformat the data however you like.